# Django generic relation field lookup

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I currently want to build up a adaptive user interface. For that I log certain actions (I call them conditions) that a user produces, when he interacts with the system. So for example, if he selects a supplier in a list this would result in a condition associated to the user, with action "select supplier" and the supplier object as value.

To accomplish this and keep it generic, I utilized the generic relations. So my condition model looks like this:

```
class Condition(models.Model):
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    value = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey("User")
    count= models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Sticking to the example above here is my supplier model:

```
class Supplier(CatalogueItem):

    conditions = generic.GenericRelation(Condition)
```

What I now want to achieve is to query all suppliers and order them by the count of their condition, produced by the current user. What I would do right now is something like

```
Supplier.objects.filter(conditions__user = user).order_by("conditions__count")
```

Problem is, that this way all suppliers that have never been selected are not included in the result. So what I now tried was:

```
Supplier.objects.filter(Q(conditions__user = user) | Q(conditions__user__isnull = True)).order_by("conditions__count")
```

The problem is, that it does not work. It seems, as if the `__isnull` operator doesn't affect the query at all (I tried various variations).

Do you know any way to achieve this without hardcoding SQL? Because writing the SQL for this query may be simple but I have some other queries were the SQL can get pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is ticket about it https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11347 try to use distinct filtering.